# Why does this stored procedure try to convert nvarchar to int when executing

Tags: sql-server

For some reason when executing this it trys to convert the nvarchar return value to int in execution. in case it matters that return value from the table is also nvarchar.

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'test $25' to data type int.

Code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProc]  
    (@testString varchar (5),
     @testNum int)  
AS  
    DECLARE @ResultValue nvarchar (20) 

    SELECT @ResultValue = returnThisString 
    FROM [database].[dbo].[myTable]  
    WHERE testString = @testString AND testNum = @testNum

    IF (@ResultValue > 0)
        SELECT @ResultValue
    ELSE
        RETURN '-1'

----    

DECLARE @return_value nvarchar(20)

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[myProc]
        @testString = 'HM',
        @testNum = 29604879

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Comment: You have `if(@ResultValue > 0)` so it's implied that it's an int?

Comment: How are you trying to execute the SP? Also, `SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value` is deprecated syntax (and *incredibly* confusing with a `variable`). `'{Literal String Alias}' = {Expression}` won't work in a future version. Stick to things like `{expression} = {[Alias]/"Alias"}` or `{[Alias]/"Alias"} = Expression`.

Comment: i used if(@ResultValue > 0) to see if there was a record, probably should just use @@rowcount, but either way im not sure why it says its nvarchar and tries to convert it to int on the execution

Comment: if you want to check if it has a value, you should use `IS NOT NULL`. The string `'a'` can't have a value `> 0` as it's not an `int`.

Comment: testNum is declared as an int in the procedure and on the table. essentially im trying to use c# VS webservice to pass a string and int and then return the nvarchar value that it finds on the table based off the string/int

Comment: agreed @Larnu however is it not safe to assume if i do @@ROWCOUNT>0 that it found the record?

Comment: Provided that you reference `@@ROWCOUNT` **immediately** afterwards, then it would be fine; but referencing the assign variable seems the *better* approach.

Comment: gotcha, will keep that in mind, other than some minor changes for best practice tho, any ideas as to why sql is trying to convert it to int when in both the procedure and the execution its is declared and selected as nvarchar

Comment: @bBach1997 the error refers to the value `test $25`...where does that come from? Is it from your `returnThisString` column in your table? If so it's being passed into `@ResultValue`. Later the code then runs `IF (@ResultValue > 0)` - and clearly you cannot compare `test $25` to `0`, it doesn't make any sense. Is it that line which fails? The error message should give you a line number.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `RETURN` value is an internal feature that you should not use and it is harcoded as an `INT` value.

If you want to return some values, you must use the `OUTPUT` keyword feature for some parameters.

As an example, your procedure should be recoded as :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.myProc @testString varchar (5),
                           @testNum int,
                           @ResultValue nvarchar (20) OUTPUT
AS  
    SELECT @ResultValue = returnThisString 
    FROM [database].[dbo].[myTable]  
    WHERE testString = @testString AND testNum = @testNum;

    IF (@ResultValue < 0)
       SET  @ResultValue = '-1';
GO


DECLARE @return_value nvarchar(20)

EXEC   [dbo].[myProc]
        @testString = 'HM',
        @testNum = 29604879,
        @ResultValue = @return_value OUTPUT:

SELECT  @return_value AS 'Return Value' 
GO
```

Comment: I will try to implement this in just a minute, another user suggested @ResultValue IS NOT NULL, is there a reason you did <0 instead?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `RETURN`. The OP is using a result set, and returning `-1` as the `RETURN` value if it doesn't get a value.